# Profiler doesn't send metrics to CloudGuru

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codeguru

I have Lambda function that is integrated with Code Guru. I want make some profiling. I added needed layer and enviroment variables. I changed runtine to Java 8 (Corretto). I also added permission for role that is used to execute Lambda.

In Cloud Watch I see logs from profiler. Last colected log is

```
INFO: Attempting to report profile data: start=2020-12-15T13:14:14.639Z end=2020-12-15T13:20:05.534Z force=false memoryRefresh=false numberOfTimesSampled=28
```

I've seen in other examples that I should have more logs with information about succes or failure like this:

```
PM software.amazon.codeguruprofilerjavaagent.ProfilingCommand submitProfilingData
INFO: Successfully reported profile
```

but it didn't happen. There is no information. What can be reason of this?